# How to add .env file or otherwise set environment variables in a Heroku app?

Tags: heroku

I've tried many different solutions on the web for this problem, but all have been unsuccessful.

Here's the problem: My app needs to know whether it is being run on Heroku (production mode) or locally (development mode). For this purpose, we want to use environment variables. I've understood that environment variables on Heroku can be set in a `.env` file. So my attempt was to run `heroku run bash -a <app-name>` and then to install vim by doing this:

```
mkdir ~/vim
cd ~/vim

# Staically linked vim version compiled from https://github.com/ericpruitt/static-vim
# Compiled on Jul 20 2017
curl 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bengoa/vim-static.tar.gz' | tar -xz

export VIMRUNTIME="$HOME/vim/runtime"
export PATH="$HOME/vim:$PATH"
cd -
```

Apart from crashing repeatedly, vim didn't work anymore when I logged in and out of the shell:

```
~ $ vim // in the heroku shell
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried `heroku plugins:install heroku-vim` but running `heroku vim` after that only resulted in a long delay followed by the normal heroku shell opening, no vim.

I don't really care if I get vim to work. I just want to be able to write in a file named `.env` on Heroku so I can set environment variables in it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried running it from the UI, i.e in heroku dashboard for the app, go to settings and set up you environmental variables?

Comment: How is installing Vim even remotely related to setting environment variables?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've explained. The intention was to create a .env file using vim. But I ended up just doing `echo "NODE_ENV=production" >> .env` instead

Comment: @Sahand, that won't work. Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will cause that file to be lost very quickly. Also, the `.env` file won't be available on other dynos if you scale your app.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no need for an `.env` file on Heroku. In fact, such a file won't work very well since

- Heroku gets all of its files from your Git repository,
- has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), meaning that changes to files like `.env` will be quickly lost, and
- the `.env` file won't be available on other dynos if you scale your app

As such, creating an `.env` file on Heroku isn't a good approach.

Instead, you can use its [built-in support for environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), using `heroku config:set <var> <value>` or its web UI. Either way, you'll get a regular environment variable.

Comment: But for testing these config vars in local, we need to set up a .env file, as recommended by Heroku here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file

Comment: @ASR4, that's one option for local development. Any method of setting environment variables will work though. In any case, this question is specifically about setting them on Heroku.

Comment: I actually am trying to accomplish the same. I have created a .env file in my project's root directory and I am trying to access it using System.getenv(). But I am getting a null. Any clue on what I may be missing?Thanks.

Comment: @ASR4, the `.env` file isn't magic. You need a tool to read it and inject the values into your application's environment. Are you running your application via `heroku local` or something else? I guess you're working with Java?

Comment: Check your gitignore if you need .env files tracked. Alternatively the heroku ui as suggested by the answer works fine.

Comment: @ASR4 I use .env locally before deploying into Heroku. I need to use 'dotenv` to support reading my env var. Here is the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv. You should try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an environment file (`.env`) and want to pass all variables to the Heroku CLI, one can run this command from a shell script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Remove comments and any spaces in lines
heroku config:set --app $1 $(sed 's:#.*$::g' "$2" | tr -d ' ')
```

The first variable `$1` being the Heroku application name and the second variable `$2` being the environment file containing key-value pairs. `sed` removes spaces and `tr` removes spaces. `sed` could probably do both but it's good enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

It is fairly simple.
Just as you added them in your .env file, do the same with heroku's command line and you will see heroku restart and you are all set to fly again.
Just use the command :
(heroku config:set VARIABLE=this_is_the_value)
Remember to use the underscores in the value as spaces are not allowed not inverted quotes (" ")to turn it into a single string is permissible.