# MONGO_URI in .env not working when deploying in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, dotenv

I'm trying to deploy an app on heroku but i can't if i use dotenv. This code doesn't work:

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  console.log("Connected to db successfully");
});
```

But this does:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.j0you.mongodb.net/ecommerce?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  console.log("Connected to db successfully");
});
```

When i try to use dotenv heroku throws this error:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add .env file or otherwise set environment variables in a Heroku app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905070/how-to-add-env-file-or-otherwise-set-environment-variables-in-a-heroku-app)

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to heroku dashboard> settings> config vars and then add the key as MONGO_URI and the mongo url value that mongodb gave me

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure of two things

1. go to heroku dashboard> settings> config vars and then add the key as MONGO_URI and the mongo url value that mongodb gave me... this info is in the .env file of your project. you might have with another name like DATA_BASE_MONGO just make sure to use that name and key in the config vars.
2. Heroku dynamically assigns your app a port, so you can't set the port to a fixed number. Heroku adds the port to the env, so you can pull it from there. Switch your listen to this: **.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)**, probably yo have it like .listen(5000), just make sure to change it.
   And thats`s it you will have your app running.

Comment: Also it should be like this: `MONGO_URI=mongodb://accountAdmin03:MY_PASSWORD@MY_IP:32492/?authSource=djongo-test&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false`. To be honest Mongo DB is far more uneasy and complicated and memory leaked. We started using surreal DB