# Enviroment variables for production and development (heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I have an app on Heroku (Node.js/Express + Postgres) and I want to use different databases for production and development.
I know that I should use variables from `process.env` instead of hardcoded values inside my code.
I think that I shouldn't use the `if` statement inside my code for checking if my environment is the production or local development. 
For me, I should create 1 variable inside the `.env` file and then my server/environment should choose by itself which option is correct.
(I mean that I should write check operator inside of `.env` file or have 2 different `.env` files and then bash script decides which to run.)
So the question is:
**Which way is the best for switching my `process.env.DATABASE_URL` depending on the environment I currently work in?**
P. S. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.env` files _at all_ on Heroku. Such files are just a convenient way to set environment variables in development. They are never required. In production on Heroku, use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), which are injected into your environment. See the following link for more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add .env file or otherwise set environment variables in a Heroku app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905070/how-to-add-env-file-or-otherwise-set-environment-variables-in-a-heroku-app)

Comment: @Chris O'k, I think I got it. Correct me if I wrong.
My code have smth like `process.env.DATABASE_URL`. Inside .env file (which is ignored by Git) I'm setting `DATABASE_URL` to `my_local_database_connection` and use it in development. When I push it to Heroku I use config vars inside Heroku, that means that it "creates .env file" (or smth like this) from my config vars on Heroku server and use that values on production.
So in my code I have only 1 line of code for both prod & dev, yeah? (Main idea that I have same var names for every enviroment)

Comment: You got it! The only thing I'll correct is that _both_ mechanisms set [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and environnement variables are what you can access via `process.env`. There's still no `.env` _file_ on Heroku. You don't even need `.env` in development if you want to set your environment variables some other way, but it's a convenient option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. My code has a line with environment variable, i.e `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

Inside the `.env` file (which is ignored by Git) I'm setting `DATABASE_URL` to `my_local_database_connection` and using it in development. When I push it to Heroku I use `config vars` inside Heroku, which means that it "creates .env file" (or smth like this) from my config vars on the Heroku server and use that values on production.

Also, as Big Person who commented on my question said, you can set your [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) in a different way, you don't have to have `.env` file in your project, but it is a handy option.

So in my code, I have only 1 line for both prod & dev. (The main idea is that I have the same var names for every environment)