# heroku nodemodule nodejs sequelize just point to 127.0.0.1 not my own server database

Tags: node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

first i have my database server public ip for example `101.50.x.x` and then when i tried
`heroku local` its work to pointing the database.

but in heroku side , the error look like these

```
2022-08-09T13:34:25.038960+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running on port 20742.
2022-08-09T13:34:25.039022+00:00 app[web.1]: run mode on :  production
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069353+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069355+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new SequelizeErrors.ConnectionRefusedError(err);
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069355+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069356+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069357+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069370+00:00 app[web.1]: at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069370+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069371+00:00 app[web.1]: at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069371+00:00 app[web.1]: at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069372+00:00 app[web.1]: at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069372+00:00 app[web.1]: at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:301:26
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069373+00:00 app[web.1]: at async MySQLQueryInterface.tableExists (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:102:17)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069373+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Function.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:939:21)
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069373+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Sequelize.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:373:9) {
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069374+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069374+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069375+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069375+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069375+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069376+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069376+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069376+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069377+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069377+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069377+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069378+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069378+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069378+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069379+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069379+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069379+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069379+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-09T13:34:25.069379+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

its shown my nodemodule pointing to `127.0.0.1` not my own ip address `101.50.x.x`

i dont understand about `heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite`
its need to be add whatever when we use outside server database **we must add addons on heroku ( mysql ) ?** or how ?

this my `.sequelizerc` file

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('src/config', 'config.js'), // i put on this configuration for database connection
  'models-path': path.resolve('src/db', 'models'), // and load config in index.js in models folder
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/db', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/db', 'migrations'),
};
```

here is full of my **index.js on models folder**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
// const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test';
const config = require('@config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, prettyPrint } = format;

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    // label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
    timestamp(),
    format.splat(),
    prettyPrint(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
    new (transports.Console)({'timestamp':true})
    ]
})

logger.log({
  label: 'winston',
  level: 'info',
  message: `winston starting`
});

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
      host: config.host,
      dialect: config.dialect,
      logging: (msg) => logger.debug('debugging: ', msg),
      operatorsAliases: 0,
      pool: {
        max: config.pool.max,
        min: config.pool.min,
        acquire: config.pool.acquire,
        idle: config.pool.idle,
      },
      timezone: config.timezone,
      define: {
        "createdAt": "created_at",
        "updatedAt": "updated_at",
        "deletedAt": "deleted_at"
      } /*don't forget to add host, port, dialect, etc.*/

  });
}
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('Connection has been established successfully.', config); // in here its show correct pointing if i deploy on my own server or local server, but in heroku not printing this line code. its stop / crashed by node_modules sequelize that connecting to 127.0.0.1:3306 dunno why .
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

// database core
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + '/core/')
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/core/', file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

// database
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
    db[model.name] = model;
    // console.log(`model name ${model.name}`);
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and here is my **config.js**

```
// TODO MULTIPLE DATABASE
// TODO OTHER DRIVE DATABASE
const fs = require('fs');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, prettyPrint } = format;

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    // label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
    timestamp(),
    format.splat(),
    prettyPrint(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
    new transports.Console(),
    ]
})

var mysql = require ('mysql2');
var pool = mysql.createPool ({
  host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOSTNAME,
  user: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
});
module.exports = pool;

module.exports = {
  development: {
    use_env_variable: true,
    username: process.env.DEV_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DEV_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEV_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DEV_DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.DEV_DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: (msg) => logger.info(`loggin development:  ${msg}`),
    dialectOptions: {
      bigNumberStrings: true,
      useUTC: false
    },
    timezone: "+08:00",
    // OVERRIDE CORE NAME
    define : {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at",
      deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  },
  test: {
    use_env_variable: true,
    username: process.env.CI_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.CI_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.CI_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.CI_DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: (msg) => logger.info(`loggin test:  ${msg}`),
    dialectOptions: {
      bigNumberStrings: true,
      useUTC: false
    },
    timezone: "+08:00",
    // OVERRIDE CORE NAME
    define : {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at"
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  },
  production: {
    use_env_variable: true,
    username: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.PROD_DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: (msg) => logger.info(`loggin production:  ${msg}`),
    dialectOptions: {
      bigNumberStrings: true,
      // ssl: {
      //   ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mysql-ca-master.crt')
      // },
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
      useUTC: false
    },
    timezone: "+08:00",
    // OVERRIDE CORE NAME
    define : {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at",
      deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 50000,
      idle: 20000
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you configuring your database credentials? I suspect you're doing it in a `.env` file locally?

Comment: let me wait to modif my question to description about the `.env`

Comment: ah i got it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49920282/8122500